# If an atom emits a visible photon doesn't that mean it's visible?

Tags: visible-light, atoms

A visible photon can be emitted and absorbed by an individual atom. Is this process sufficient for saying that we can see an individual atom with visible light? I realize the wavelength of visible light is larger than a typical atomic diameter, that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: If you couldn't see the light emitted from individual atoms, how would we see anything at all?

Comment: @Asher: reflection of light is a collective phenomenon involving many atoms. The emission of light from individual atoms plays little part in normal vision.

Comment: My point was more that vision relies on the mass collection of individual photons, regardless of source. I don't see how perception of large numbers of photons would be possible if the eye's sensitivity to each individual photon were flat zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say:

> we can see an individual atom with visible light

you need to clarify what you mean by the word *see*. As you say, there is no problem detecting that an atom is there because we can measure the light it emits, however it will appear as a point source and we cannot use the light to measure its size or shape. To measure the size and shape of the atom would require distinguishing between light rays emitted from different points on the atom, but because the atom is so much smaller than the wavelength of light we cannot do this.